# Dictionary equivalent data structure?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, dictionary

I'm working in JavaScript and want to keep a list of set km/mph approximations to hand. (I can't convert programmatically, I'm working with an external API that expects certain values, so it really does have to be a dictionary equivalent.)

Currently I'm using an object:

```
var KM_MPH = { 10: 16, 12: 20, 15: 24 };
```

Going from mph to km is pretty easy:

```
var km = KM_MPH[10];
```

How do I find mph, given km? Also, is an object the best data structure to use for this sort of thing in JavaScript? I'm more used to Python.

Comment: try to define an other array object for MPH_KM?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what the external API's requirements are?  It's possible you could set up a function that would return values in the range and format the API expects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A basic JavaScript object is in fact the best choice here. To find a reverse mapping, you can do:

```
function mphToKM(val){
    for(var km in KM_MPH){
        if(KM_MPH[km] === val){
            return km;
        } 
    }

    return null;
}
```

Or, if you anticipate having to do a lot of lookups, I would recommend having a secondary JS Object that is the mirror of the first

```
var mph_km = {};
for(var km in KM_MPH){
    mph_km[KM_MPH[km]] = km;
}

// mph_km[16] ==> 10
```

I don't know if you are in fact doing this for conversion between kilometres per hour to miles per hour... if so, it seems to make more sense to just do the conversion directly instead of relying on a hash mapping of the values.

```
var conversionRate = 1.609344; // kilometres per mile
function kphToMPH(val){
    return val / conversionRate ;
}

function mphToKPH(val){
    return val * conversionRate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is much closer to a `Dictionary` data structure, since you can have dozens of elements:

```
var dictionary = [
    { key: 10, value: 12 },
    { key: 12, value: 20 },
    { key: 15, value: 24 }
];
```

Then you can also use some *JavaScript Framework* like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to filter elements:

```
var element = $.filter(dictionary, function() {
    return $(this).attr("key") == 10;
});

alert($(element).attr("value"));
```

Comment: This would be a poor choice.  The lookup would be O(n) and there's a possibility of multiple values for the same key.

Comment: The question asked with emphasis "the equivalent of a Dictionary in JavaScript". Well, this is exactly equivalent: `array` of `objects` with `Key/Value pair`. The way of reading these elements is only a suggestion and does not change the fact that the question has been answered with exactly what was requested. Any response that does not rely on array of objects with key/value pair isn't a Dictionary and therefore does not answer the question.

Comment: It's true that the JS object doesn't have properties named Key and Value but that's immaterial.  The closest JS equivalent to a dictionary **is** the object.  A key lookup in a JS object and a Dictionary both approcah O(1).  Your array is O(n) - a scan is required to lookup the key.  Also, a Dictionary does not typically support multiple values per key - your array does.  In trying to force the key/value structure onto JS, you completely miss out on the performance benefits of the JS object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iterate over all entries to find to find your key 
Mostly a dict is used to from key=>value

Alternatively you can have two lists 
var km = [];
var mph = [];

with their corresponding indices mapped

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the JavaScript object is the correct choice.

Create a second object to do the reverse lookup:

```
var i, MPH_KM = {};
for(i in KM_MPH) MPH_KM[KM_MPH[i]] = i;

var mph = MPH_KM[16];
```

Comment: I forgot to mention... in JS, object keys are always type string.  When you create the MPH_KM object, the values will be type string because they are the KM_MPH keys.  If you want integers, you can replace `= i` with `= parseInt(i)`.  If you have decimals, it would be `= parseFloat(i)`.

Comment: apparently someone doesn't like the reverse mapping idea, ic3b3rg.  Downvotes for the both of us, with no explanation.

Comment: @Matt... I see that :S  The reverse-lookup is definitely the right approach.  Hopefully @phil123 will look beyond the votes.

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary equivalent structure for a javascript object would look like this:

```
var dictionary = { keys:[], values:[] };
```

Above structure is an equivalent of

```
Dictionary(Of Type, Type) **For VB.Net**
Dictionary<Type, Type>) **For C#.Net**
```

Hope this helps!